# PyWinAuto automation of notepad example vs 'reallife' example

Tags: python, pywinauto

What I need to do is click a menu item and load a file. Love the well documented notepad example, which goes something like this...

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application (backend="uia").start("notepad.exe")
app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("File->SaveAs")
Sub=app.UntitledNotepad.child_window(title_re="Save As", class_name="#32770")
Sub.FileNameCombo.type_keys("temp_12345.txt")
```

Works Great. however, when I adapt this code for my application and try running menu_select an 'AttributeError' exception is raised. I am fairly certain this is because the menu strip in my application is of type uia_controls.MenuWrapper and does not support menu_select

I have tried a different approach - as shown below

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\myapplication.exe")
time.sleep(1)
win = app.MyApplication
win['File'].select() # exapnd submenu
#Added AFTER I asked the question - i finally worked it out...
sub = win['File']
loadConfigMenuItem = (sub.children()[0])
loadConfigMenuItem.click_input() #print statement is executed
#loadConfigMenuItem.select() #print statement is NOT executed until I close the dialog box
print("If this prints, then I am a happy Man")
```

this expands the file menu. However, from this point on I am unable to access the child elements of this menu. Any Ideas please???

Comment: think I answered my own question on this one.

Comment: think I answered my own question on this one. I edited the code to show the use of click_input. Please note that there is a huge difference between click_input and select. using select 'clicks' the menu item and opens a corresponding windows 'Open' dialog box but no code is executed after the call to select until AFTER the dialog box is closed. Using click_input means code is run after the dialog box is opened, therefore allowing me to automate 'stuff' with the dialog box :-)

Comment: Yes, it's kind of wrong blocking handler on app side. Only `click_input()` workaround helps here if you don't use threading. I'm thinking on non-blocking threading implementation in the future to hide details for users, but it's a very long term plan. Please post your own answer and accept it. It's OK on StackOverflow. Also a signal for others that problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question. Look at the code listing, especially

```
loadConfigMenuItem.click_input()
```

Key here is that this clicks the menu item and continues executing, thus enabling me to get a reference to the dialog box that appears after clicking the menu item

Conversely, If you were to use

```
loadConfigMenuItem.select()
```

then no code is executed after this call until the dialog box is closed